# How to repeatedly search the same file 'n' number of times using perl?

Tags: perl

What I am actually trying to do is, extract range of lines from a text file and print the ranges in another file. The start range of strings are stored in @secarr and corresponding end range of strings are stored in @exarr. 
The problem now I am facing is that $secarr[4] and $exarr[4] range is found near the EOF and hence the output file ends till there. But $secarr[5] and $exarr[5] and many other ranges are present before  $secarr[4] and $exarr[4] range.

Please suggest me a way out.

Thanks in advance,
Faez

Comment: Can you give an example of what your input is and code that you currently have?

Comment: What size of file do you expect?

Answer (score 3):

The simple approach is to reopen the file for each range. You can also try:

- If the file is not huge, you can read it to an array (`my @array = <$IN>;`). For each range, you just print the array slice.
- You can go over the file just once, checking whether you are entering/leaving any range on each line. Remember the currently active ranges and output each line to all of them (can your ranges overlap?)

Comment: Even if the ranges DO overlap, one can create a temp file for every range, then join the files in order, case closed.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to have a look at [Tie::File](http://perldoc.perl.org/Tie/File.html), which gives you a simple interface to the records of your file.